# Обводка у кнопки

Tags: html, css

Как убрать обводку у кнопки, при применении на нее `background-color` ?

```css
.but {
  background-color: yellow;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" class="but">
```

Comment: Что за кнопка ? что за обводка ? вы о  стиле --  outline:none;

Comment: HTML:
<input type="button" value="click" class="but">
CSS:
.but {
 background-color: yellow;
 outline: none;
}

Comment: @Serp обновил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type="button"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" class="but">
```